# So if there's multiple sentences in a list and I want to search for a word, how do I make it so it only searches the first word of each sentence?

Tags: python, string, search

```
list = ["This is an example", "Hello there! This is an example"]


search = input("Search: ")

for title in list:
    if search in title:
        print(title)
```

```
#Output
Search: This
This is an example
Hello there! This is an example
```

So what this does is search for the string that is attached to (search) but I only want it to search for a keyword that is the first letter of a sentence. So since I typed "This" in (search) I want it to only search and print "This is an example" because "This" was the first word of a sentence.

Comment: Don't use `list` builtin as variable name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` the sentence and compare with the first word like so:

```
l = ["This is an example", "Hello there! This is an example"]
search = input("Search: ")
for title in l:
    if search == title.split()[0]:
        print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter answer using list comprehension:

```
l = ["This is an example", "Hello there! This is an example"]
s = input("Enter search string : ").lower()   #lower function for case-less comparison
print("".join([i for i in l if i.split()[0].lower() == s]))
```

I wouldn't suggest this answer if you aren't aware of list comprehension concepts though. Probably go for answer by @not_speshal, as mine is shorter version of her code.

Comment: *her. Also just wanted to stick to OP's original code as far as possible.

Comment: I am so sorry for assuming gender. Will make the edit!